# Error when use jQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote two functions in one PHP file:

```
function f1()
{
     //sample code
     $('some_div').load('file.php');
     f2();
}

function f2()
{
    var new_element = document.getElementById('some_id');
    // some_id is the id of element from file.php
    //sample code
}
```

I receive the following error:

> new_element is null

However, if I add `alert("test");` before `f2();` in the `f1()` function there is no error.

How can I make this work without the `alert()` statement?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this -

```
function f1(){
     //sample code
     $('#some_div').load('file.php',f2); // call f2 when load is complete 
}
```

`f2()` will be called when load is complete, so the loaded element will be available for use by other function

Edit :

passing parameters to `f2()`

```
function f1(){
     //sample code
     $('#some_div').load('file.php',function(){
         f2(yourParameters);
     }); 
}
```

- http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @loithuxua Are you sure their is an element with id `some_id` ?

Comment: i am sure, because if I put alert('test') before f2(); in f1 function, there is no error. I think the problem is not syntax error.

Comment: Yes their is no issue with syntax, the issue is with the asynchronous behaviour of `.load()` , You are calling `f2()` before your data is even loaded, that causes your `getElementById` return undefined.

Comment: Yes,  I Think  asynchronous, but I load function of jQuery, can I use paramter in callback function?

Comment: Thank you very much! there is not error. But I want to know what is different between f2(parameter) and function(){f2(parameter)}?

Answer (score 1):

The .load() function features a success callback that you can use :

```
function f1(){
     $('#some_div').load('file.php',f2);
}
```